# XSLT Conversion with matching of nodes and sum.

Tags: xslt

I have the following xml for conversion:

```
<IFX xmlns="http://www.ifxforum.org/181/ifxschema">
  <MediaSvcRq>
    <MediaAcctAdjAddRq>
      <MediaAcctAdjInfo>
        <MediaTrnType>Dispense</MediaTrnType>
        <CurAmt>
          <Amt>1800.00</Amt>
          <CurCode>PHP</CurCode>
        </CurAmt>
        <MediaItem>
          <MediaContainerId>Cassette 2</MediaContainerId>
          <MediaType>Cash</MediaType>
          <Count>3</Count>
          <MediaBal>
            <CurAmt>
              <Amt>500.00</Amt>
              <CurCode>PHP</CurCode>
            </CurAmt>
            <MediaTotal>
              <MediaTotalType>Dispensed</MediaTotalType>
              <Count>3</Count>
            </MediaTotal>
          </MediaBal>
        </MediaItem>
        <MediaItem>
          <MediaContainerId>CashRetainBin</MediaContainerId>
          <MediaType>Cash</MediaType>
          <Count>3</Count>
          <MediaBal>
            <CurAmt>
              <Amt>500.00</Amt>
              <CurCode>PHP</CurCode>
            </CurAmt>
            <MediaTotal>
              <MediaTotalType>Retained</MediaTotalType>
              <Count>3</Count>
            </MediaTotal>
          </MediaBal>
        </MediaItem>
        <MediaItem>
          <MediaContainerId>Cassette 3</MediaContainerId>
          <MediaType>Cash</MediaType>
          <Count>3</Count>
          <MediaBal>
            <CurAmt>
              <Amt>100.00</Amt>
              <CurCode>PHP</CurCode>
            </CurAmt>
            <MediaTotal>
              <MediaTotalType>Dispensed</MediaTotalType>
              <Count>3</Count>
            </MediaTotal>
          </MediaBal>
        </MediaItem>
        <MediaItem>
          <MediaContainerId>CashRetainBin</MediaContainerId>
          <MediaType>Cash</MediaType>
          <Count>3</Count>
          <MediaBal>
            <CurAmt>
              <Amt>100.00</Amt>
              <CurCode>PHP</CurCode>
            </CurAmt>
            <MediaTotal>
              <MediaTotalType>Retained</MediaTotalType>
              <Count>3</Count>
            </MediaTotal>
          </MediaBal>
        </MediaItem>
      </MediaAcctAdjInfo>
    </MediaAcctAdjAddRq>
  </MediaSvcRq>
</IFX>
```

And I would like to have the following output:

```
<XML>
            <!--Information of Message Container ID: Cassette 1-->
            <F70><!--//MediaItem/MediaBal/CurAmt/Amt-->
            </F70>
            <F71><!--//MediaItem/MediaBal/CurAmt/CurCode-->
            </F71>
            <F72><!--//MediaItem/MediaBal/MediaTotal/Count-->
            </F72>
            <!--Information of Message Container ID: Cassette 2-->
            <F73><!--//MediaItem/MediaBal/CurAmt/Amt-->
            500.00
            </F73>
            <F74><!--//MediaItem/MediaBal/CurAmt/CurCode-->
            PHP
            </F74>
            <F75><!--//MediaItem/MediaBal/MediaTotal/Count-->
            3
            </F75>
            <!--Information of Message Container ID: Cassette 3-->
            <F76><!--//MediaItem/MediaBal/CurAmt/Amt-->
            100.00
            </F76>
            <F77><!--//MediaItem/MediaBal/CurAmt/CurCode-->
            PHP
            </F77>
            <F78><!--//MediaItem/MediaBal/MediaTotal/Count-->
            3
            </F78>
            <!--Information of Message Container ID: Cassette 4-->
            <F79><!--//MediaItem/MediaBal/CurAmt/Amt-->
            </F79>
            <F80><!--//MediaItem/MediaBal/CurAmt/CurCode-->
            </F80>
            <F81><!--//MediaItem/MediaBal/MediaTotal/Count-->
            </F81>
            <F82><!--Sum of //MediaItem/Count for CashRetainBin-->
            </F82>
```

For each Cassette, I have tried the following:

```
<F70>
<xsl:value-of select="//ifx:MediaSvcRq/ifx:MediaAcctAdjAddRq/ifx:MediaAcctAdjInfo/ifx:MediaItem[ifx:MediaContainerId='Cassette 1']/ifx:MediaBal/ifx:CurAmt/ifx:Amt"/>
</F70>
```

I think matching the Cassettes would work.

The problem I have is the sum of CashRetainBin. How can I match the Message Container ID to get the sum of CashRetainBin?

Comment: The same way you matched it for the individual cassettes, using a predicate.  How about `sum(//ifx:MediaItem[ifx:MediaContainerId='CashRetainBin']/ifx:MediaBal/ifx:CurAmt/ifx:Amt)`

Comment: I have tried creating a variable with Sum of CashRetainBin and it is is returning an error. 
  <xsl:variable name="CashRetainBin">
   <xsl:value-of select="SUM(//ifx:MediaSvcRq/ifx:MediaAcctAdjAddRq/ifx:MediaAcctAdjInfo/ifx:MediaItem[ifx:MediaContainerId='CashRetainBin']/ifx:MediaBal/ifx:MediaTotal/ifx:Count">
  </xsl:variable>

Comment: ConvertRead: error[1003] - [Error process transform: 
Could not find function: SUM()
pattern = 'SUM(//ifx:MediaSvcRq/ifx:MediaAcctAdjAddRq/ifx:MediaAcctAdjInfo/ifx:MediaItem[ifx:MediaContainerId='CashRetainBin']/ifx:MediaBal/ifx:MediaTotal/ifx:Count'
Remaining tokens: ('SUM' '(' '/' '/' 'ifx' ':' 'MediaSvcRq' '/' 'ifx' ':' 'MediaAcctAdjAddRq' '/' 'ifx' ':' 'MediaAcctAdjInfo' '/' 'ifx' ':' 'MediaItem' '[' 'ifx' ':' 'MediaContainerId' '=' ''CashRetainBin'' ']' '/' 'ifx' ':' 'MediaBal' '/' 'ifx' ':' 'MediaTotal' '/' 'ifx' ':' 'Count')
]

Comment: XPath is case-sensitive - the function is called `sum`, not `SUM`.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
   xmlns:ifx="http://www.ifxforum.org/181/ifxschema" exclude-result-prefixes="ifx"
   >
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="ifx:MediaAcctAdjInfo">
    <XML>
      <xsl:call-template name="ProcessCassettes" />
      <F82>
        <xsl:value-of select="sum(ifx:MediaItem[ifx:MediaContainerId = 'CashRetainBin']/ifx:Count)"/>
      </F82>
    </XML>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="ProcessCassettes">
    <xsl:param name="cassetteNo" select="1" />

    <xsl:variable name="startingNo" select="67 + 3 * $cassetteNo" />
    <xsl:variable name="mediaItem" select="ifx:MediaItem[ifx:MediaContainerId = concat('Cassette ', $cassetteNo)]"/>

    <xsl:element name="F{$startingNo}">
      <xsl:value-of select="$mediaItem/ifx:MediaBal/ifx:CurAmt/ifx:Amt"/>
    </xsl:element>
    <xsl:element name="F{$startingNo + 1}">
      <xsl:value-of select="$mediaItem/ifx:MediaBal/ifx:CurAmt/ifx:CurCode"/>
    </xsl:element>
    <xsl:element name="F{$startingNo + 2}">
      <xsl:value-of select="$mediaItem/ifx:MediaBal/ifx:MediaTotal/ifx:Count"/>
    </xsl:element>

    <xsl:if test="$cassetteNo &lt; 4">
      <xsl:call-template name="ProcessCassettes">
        <xsl:with-param name="cassetteNo" select="$cassetteNo + 1" />
      </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```